# Determinar si un array es creciente o no en Java

Tags: java, array, condiciones

He de determinar si la serie de números que escribo por teclado forman un array creciente o no. Esta es la tercera o cuarta versión del programa. No funciona porque en la condición de

```
if(num < lista[i])
```

debería poner otra cosa en vez de lista[i], para que así el programa pueda comprender que me estoy refiriendo al número anterior, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Este es el código:

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
int[] lista = new int[10];
int num, cont = 0;
    
for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Introduce el valor de la posición "+i);  
    num = teclado.nextInt();

    if(num > lista[i]){
        cont++;
    }
    else{
        cont--;
    }

    lista[i] = num;
}

if(con == 10){
    System.out.println("Es creciente");
}
else{
    System.out.println("No es creciente");
}
```

Comment: Una pequeña mejora: define una constante con el número de valores a leer. O usa lista.length en el if en lugar de 10; es decir, hay dos 10 en tu código y no hay una relación explícita y clara entre ellos cuando se lee el código.

Comment: Hola Marta, podrías decirnos si las respuestas dadas te resultaron útiles y marcar como aceptada la que consideres mejor, recuerda que también puedes emitir votos, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, al final, con ayuda de un compañero, llegué a la conclusión de cómo averiguar si es creciente o no sin necesidad ni de crear booleanos.

Básicamente si asignas el valor introducido como el máximo (haciendo que el valor inical máximo sea Integer.MIN_VALUE), después de haberlo guardado en el array, al introducir el siguiente, puede comprobar si es más grande o no, y cuando el contador es 10, entonces significa que es creciente.

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int[] lista = new int[10];
    int num, cont = 0, max =  Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduce el valor de la posición "+i);  
            num = teclado.nextInt();
            if(num>max){
           lista[i] = num;
           max = num;
                cont++;
            }
            else{
                cont--;
            }
    }
    if(cont==10){
        System.out.println("Es creciente");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No es creciente");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Tendrías que considerar si es el primer número de la lista (i=0) y si no comparar con el anterior de la lista en cada caso (i-1). Te dejo un ejemplo sobre tu código para una lista de 3 elementos.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int[] lista = new int[3];
    int num, cont = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduce el valor de la posición "+i);  
            num = teclado.nextInt();
            if(i==0 || (i>0 && num>lista[i-1])) {
                cont++;
            }
            else{
                cont--;
            }
            lista[i] = num;
    }
    if(cont==3){
        System.out.println("Es creciente");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No es creciente");
    }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Te propongo que primero llenes el arreglo de números y una vez llenado analices si es creciente o no:

```
bool noCreciente = false;

for (int i = 0; i < lista.length - 1; i++) 
{
    if(lista[i] > lista[i + 1]
    {
        noCreciente = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(noCreciente)
{
   //No creciente 
}
else
{
   //Creciente 
}
```

Se declara la **variable noCreciente** de tipo **bool**, y posteriormente se ejecuta un **ciclo for** para recorrer el arreglo, se pregunta si la posición actual del arreglo es mayor a la que sigue, y de serlo esto indicaría que el arreglo no es creciente. Basta que está condición se cumpla solo una vez.

**Nota**: En realidad lo que te recomiendo es que cojas mi código y hagas una función para determinar si un arreglo es o no creciente, de esta forma podrías invocarla tantas veces como desees, en el arreglo que desees.

Comment: Igual esto lo puede hacer tambien a medida que llena el array... siempre podemos complicarselo mas ;)

Comment: @gbianchi mi idea era mas bien que con ese codigo hiciera una funcion que le sirviera para determinar que cualquier arreglo es o no creciente.

Comment: te le fuiste 5 ejercicios adelante jajaj ;)... esta perfecta esta respuesta (antes que alguien proteste algo)

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero realizar un método el cual determine si tu array es creciente o no, para esto lo recomendable es primero obtener el array y posteriormente este método determinaría en base a una iteración si el array de elementos es creciente o no:

```
private boolean growing(int[] array) {
       System.out.println(array.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length -1; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                return false; // no es creciente.
            }
        }
        return true; //es creciente
    };
```

y utilizarlo en tu código de esta forma:

```
   Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] lista = new int[10];
    int num, cont = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduce el valor de la posición "+i);
        num = teclado.nextInt();
        if(num>lista[i]){
            cont++;
        }
        else{
            cont--;
        }
        lista[i] = num;
    }
    if(growing(lista)){ 
        System.out.println("Es creciente");
    }else{
        System.out.println("No es creciente");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En este código, `numAnterior` se utiliza para almacenar el valor del número anterior en cada iteración. Luego, se compara el número actual `num` con el número anterior `numAnterior`. Esto debería permitirte determinar si la serie de números es creciente o no.

Quedaría el código más o menos así:

```
// Verifica si una serie de números es creciente
    public static boolean esCreciente() {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] lista = new int[10];
        int cont = 0;
        int numAnterior = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce el valor de la posición " + i);
            lista[i] = teclado.nextInt();

            // Compara con el número anterior
            if (lista[i] > numAnterior) {
                cont++;
            } else {
                cont--;
            }

            numAnterior = lista[i]; // Actualiza el número anterior
        }

        return cont == lista.length;
    }
```